# Why is $scope.$apply() needed here for a simple delete, and what's the recommended way (since with it, it throws an error)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just need to remove a property from an item within the scope.
Without the `$scope.$apply()`, the property isn't getting deleted.
With `$apply`, an error is thrown "[$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress".

Why, and what's the "proper" way to do this then?

```
    $scope.loadPreset = function($event){
        angular.forEach($scope.presets, function(preset, key) {
            if($scope.presets[key].hasOwnProperty('loadStatus')) {
               delete $scope.presets[key].loadStatus;
               $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
    };
```

(this works but throws a "$apply already in progress" error)

Without the `$apply`, the property isn't getting deleted. And the following (strangely) doesn't work either:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    delete $scope.presets[key].loadStatus
});
```

The function is called directly from an `hg-click` directive.

(Edited based on comments)

Comment: `$apply` isn't needed here unless `loadPreset` is tripped outside the digest cycle (it's clearly not, hence your error) - how do you know that key isn't deleted?

Comment: That was my thought as well, but it doesn't work without it. And the keys never get deleted :-). At least for now, that's a later worry.

Comment: You seem to have a weird typo anyways. `$scope.$apply` needs a function. You're passing it `delete $scope.presets[key].loadStatus`. Also, why can't you use `$scope.presets[key].loadStatus = null; delete $scope.presets[key].loadStatus` (without the apply)

Comment: Oh, right, edited. Is it needed to null out the value first? Simply `delete $scope.presets[key].loadStatus` doesn't work, I would expect this to have the same result.

Comment: Hmmm... for some reason with the function as an argument to `$scope.$apply` it isn't working either, very strange! Edited back...

Comment: @Pim My thinking was that Angular possibly doesn't detect a change in value for `delete`, whereas actually changing the value (to `null`) triggers Angular. I wasn't sure, it was just a suggestion

Comment: I can confirm that the nulling doesn't have an effect.

Comment: I think you should figure out why you need to use `$apply()` in the first place. As the comment from @tymeJV said, it shouldn't be necessary ... and that to me is the first oddity I would try to solve :) What is calling `$scope.loadPreset()`?

Comment: It's in an `ng-click` directive so I really don't get this.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the entire foreach in the apply function.  Unless it takes a long time to iterate the presets, there is not really a reason to run it for each item in the loop:

```
 $scope.loadPreset = function($event){
     $scope.$apply(function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.presets, function(preset, key) {
            if($scope.presets[key].hasOwnProperty('loadStatus')) { 
                delete $scope.presets[key].loadStatus
             }
        });
     });
    };
```

Comment: Definitely a good suggestion, but would that **fix** what's happening? It just seems like an optimization

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but same thing here: Property isn't getting deleted for some reason. It's interesting that depending on HOW I use `$scope.$apply` it seems to work or not. Only calling `$scope.$apply()` directly without a function as an argument works, or `$scope.$apply( delete ...)` (which is basically wrong syntax, but works).